# In C, how to print all the values in struct by using linked-list, while this struct is nested?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, printf

I have create two struct and two variables n1 and n2, here is the result when runnig code below:

10-nick-90.500000

20-wilson-100.500000.

What I want:

1.take elemtype variable values and put them into struct LNODE.

2.print values by using printlist(LNDOE* head).

Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemtype{
    int no;
    char* name;
    double score;
}elemtype;

typedef struct tagnode{
    elemtype data;
    struct tagnode* next;
}LNODE;

elemtype* print_elemtype(elemtype* data_to_print){
    elemtype* p = data_to_print;
    if ( p != NULL){
        printf("%d-%s-%lf", p->no,p->name,p->score);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}

void creat_link(LNODE** head, int n, void (*input)(elemtype*)){
    LNODE* s;
    *head = (LNODE*)malloc(sizeof(LNODE));
    (*head)->next = NULL;
    for(;n>0;n--){
        s = (LNODE*)malloc(sizeof(LNODE));
        input(&(s->data));
        s->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next = s;
    }
}



int main()
{
    elemtype* n1 = malloc(sizeof(elemtype));
    elemtype* n2 = malloc(sizeof(elemtype));
    n1->name = "nick";
    n1->no = 10;
    n1->score = 90.5;
    n2->name = "wilson";
    n2->no = 20;
    n2->score = 100.5;

    elemtype** s1,**s2;
    s1 = &n1;
    s2 = &n2;

    print_elemtype(n1);
    print_elemtype(n2);

    
    
    free(n1);
    free(n2);
    n1 = NULL;
    n2 = NULL;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to read variable values? Using input function and reading from the keyboard? Please clarify

Comment: Using input function, please.

Answer (score 0):

Crawl in your linked list with kind of code like this :

```
int main(void)
{
   struct_type *list = allocat_struct_type();
   struct_type *list_copy = list;  // always copy the head of the list when your manipulating the list

   while (list_copy != NULL) {
       printf("%s", list_copy->text_to_display); // text_to_display must be an str type in this exemple
       list_copy = list_copy->next;
   }
}
```

if your still having problem precise where and when.

Feel free to ask me again i hope it help you i tried to understand what you would know but it's very blurry.